# Is it possible to write an equation that represents the root of this kind of function?

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization

I have the parabola $x^2$, and a circle whose center is the point $(3,2)$. My goal was to figure out the minimum length of the circle's radius so that it would be tangent to the parabola. To do this, I decided to use the Pythagorean theorem to create a function that would show me the distances between $(3,2)$ and any point on the parabola:

$f(x)=\sqrt{(3-x)^{2}+(2-x^2)^{2}}$

Now to figure out the minimum value of $f(x)$, I needed to find the root of its derivative:

$\begin{align}
\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{(3-x)^{2}+(2-x^2)^{2}}}(-2(3-x)-4x(2-x^2))\\
=\frac{4x^3-6x-6}{2\sqrt{(3-x)^{2}+(2-x^2)^{2}}}
\end{align}$

After this, I graphed $\frac{df}{dx}$ and saw that its root was approximately $1.567$, which told me the location of the point on the parabola closest to $(3,2)$. I then used the Pythagorean theorem again to find the distance between that point and $(3,2)$, and got my answer for the radius. This is all well and good, but what if I move the center of the circle some additional distance away from the parabola? Then I would have to differentiate $f(x)$ again and use its root to find the minimum radius. Instead of doing this process over and over, is it possible to have a general equation (or set of equations) that tells me the root of $\frac{df}{dx}$ no matter where I move the circle's center point around the parabola?

Comment: the radius of the circle must be orthogonal to the parabola

Answer (score 2):

Say the centre is $(a,b)$. Then,
$$f(x)=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-x^2)^2}$$
Minimizing $f(x)$ is the same as minimizing $f(x)^2=g(x)$.
$$g(x)=(a-x)^2+(b-x^2)^2$$
Note that
$$g^\prime(x)=2(x-a)+4x(x^2-b)=4x^3-(4b-2)x-2a$$
If you wish, use the cubic formula to get that the root to the above equation is $\sqrt[3]{r_+}+\sqrt[3]{r_-}$ where
$$r_{\pm}=-a\pm\sqrt{a-\frac{(4b-2)^3}{27}}$$
(This might not always be a minimum, check it manually). Set this into the expression of $f(x)$ and you are good to go.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Wow, I really like this approach! I never thought of squaring $f(x)$ to get rid of the radical, making it convenient to differentiate while keeping the root unchanged. I tried to test the cubic root expression you provided, but it kept being undefined since the terms inside the radical sum to a negative number. For reference, here is the Desmos graph I'm using for this problem: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/m4owvkar7z. Also, sorry if I can't communicate back in a timely manner, I'm usually not available consistently throughout the day.

Comment: @VV_721: Differentiating $g(x)$ or $f(x)$ is really the same thing as the derivative of $\sqrt{g}$ is $g^\prime/2\sqrt{g}$, so the roots are the same. Anyway, even if the terms inside the radical become negative, the sum of cube roots will be real. Say $r_+=a+bi=re^{i\theta}$ and $r_-=a-bi=re^{-i\theta}$. Then, one choice of cube roots leads to $\sqrt[3]{r_+}+\sqrt[3]{r_-}=re^{i\theta/3}+re^{-i\theta/3}=r\sin(\theta/3)$, which is very much real.

Comment: I don't quite understand the notation you used, specifically $\sqrt[3]{r_+}$ and $\sqrt[3]{r_-}$. What do those mean?

Comment: @VV_721: cube roots of $r_+$ and $r_-$. (In general, there are three cube roots of any complex number, so in total you have nine possible values of $\sqrt[3]{r_+}$ and $\sqrt[3]{r_-}$, but it is always the case that those nine possibilities give three distinct roots - and at least one of them is real. If $r_+$ and $r_-$, taking the real cube root works. Else, you can take root in a way I described in my previous comment and get a real root.